# Usar una lista en varias clases - java

Tags: java, android-studio, poo, programación-móvil

Tengo una lista de objetos en una clase controlador, donde en un método voy llenando mi lista:

```
    Universidad uni;
    List<Universidad> universidades = new ArrayList<>();

public void agregarUniversidad(String nombre, int casos){
    uni = new Universidad();
    uni.setNombre(nombre);
    uni.setCasos(casos);
    universidades.add(uni);
}
```

Incluso tengo el método para retornar toda la lista:

```
public List<Universidad> returnUniversidad(){
    return universidades;
}
```

Quiero acceder a ella desde la clase de una actividad en Android. 
Aquí es donde intento usar la lista:

```
ControladorApp cApp = new ControladorApp();
private ListView lvuniversidades;
List<Universidad> nombres = cApp.returnUniversidad();
```

Aquí agrego el adaptador de la lista:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad4_list_view);

    lvuniversidades = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvuniversidades);
    ArrayAdapter<Universidad> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Universidad>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,nombres);
    lvuniversidades.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

El resultado: no se muestra ningún dato:
[image: Screenshot de la actividad]

Comment: _Distintos usos_? Así como esta, es una pregunta muy amplia. Qué intentas hacer?

Comment: Quiero acceder al contenido de la lista desde una actividad en Android (desde el archivo .java)para mostrar el contenido en un ListView.

Comment: Entonces inténtalo, incluye el código con el que lo intentas y el error o comportamiento inesperado que obtienes.

Comment: @Alfabravo , aquí están todos los detalles.

Comment: en que momento creas la lista universidades?

Comment: En el primer bloque de código, en mi clase Controller.

Comment: Puedes declarar la variable tipo final stactic o simplemente puedes pasarlo entre actividades como parametros. Intent.putextras

Comment: @AndyC tu respuesta es la definitiva! muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Intenta instanciar la controladora en el metodo onCreate():

```
private ControladorApp cApp;
private ListView lvuniversidades;
List<Universidad> nombres;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad4_list_view);

    cApp = new ControladorApp();
    cApp.agregarUniversidad("uni1", 1);
    cApp.agregarUniversidad("uni2", 3);
    nombres = cApp.returnUniversidad();

    lvuniversidades = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvuniversidades);
    ArrayAdapter<Universidad> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Universidad>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,nombres);
    lvuniversidades.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Me funciona bien al nivel de la clase activity, pero no me muestra los valores que ya guardé desde la otra actividad. Aun no accede a la lista donde guarde todos mis datos. La lista debe mostrar los datos que guardé desde el otro activity...

Answer (score 0):

Para que te muestre los datos que guardas desde otros activities yo lo que haría sería implementar el patrón Singleton.
Este es un patrón de diseño fácil de implementar y que consiste en garantizar que una clase solo tenga una instancia y proporcionar un punto de acceso global a ella.
En resumidas cuentas solo existirá un objeto Controlador para todos tus activities.

Así se podría implementar:

```
public class Singleton {

   private static final ControladorApp cApp;

   public static synchronized ControladorApp getControladorApp() {
       if (cApp == null) {
           cApp = new ControladorApp();
       }
       return cApp;
   }
}
```

Siempre que quieras el controlador deberás de crearlo de esta manera:

```
ControladorApp cApp = Singleton.getControladorApp();
```